# How to set ssl in play 2.0 application?

Tags: ssl, https, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi i am working on a play 2.0 application . I want to enable ssl for that application to make https.I followed  this documentation https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/339 , but not working .How to make https.Can any one tell me Please ?
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a front-end HTTP / HTTPS server and proxy-forwarding to your play application.

I am using [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) for that with the [HTTPSSLModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule).

You can have a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099605/595223)